# Error while passing checkbox values to a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html, checkbox

I have a checkbox which stores values from database table. So it contains an array of values when I display them on my page.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkdelt[<?php echo $id; ?>]" name="chkdelt[]" value="<?php echo $id;  ?>">
```

Above given is the checkbox code.

I have a popup block which shows the count of checked checkboxes.

```
  <div class="popup">

    Show count here <span id="numb"></span>
<button type="button" onclick="paz(<?php echo json_encode(chkdelt); ?>);">Click</button>
    </div>
```

And I am able to show the count successfully using this javascript function given below.

```
  // used to show number of checked checkboxes in popup
            function dumpInArray(){
                var arr = [];
                $('.table-responsive input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){
                    arr.push($(this).val());
                });
                return arr.length;  //returns no of checked check boxes


            }

            $('.select_chk').click(function () {
                $('#numb').html(dumpInArray());  // output of dumpInArray() written into numb span

            });
```

And I try to pass this array to a Javascript function while clicking the button inside of popup.

My Javascript is given below:

```
function paz(a)
            {
                var temp = new Array();
                temp = JSON.parse(a);
                for(i=0;i<temp.length;i++)
                {
                    alert(temp[i]);
                }
            }
```

The values are not passed to paz() in Javascript. Rest works fine. I want to pass the values of all checked checkboxes to the paz() when I click the button in the popup div.

Thanks. Help???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass argument to JavaScript function as a string.

You're passing them as a variable which in turn will be becoming as `undefined`.

To pass argument as a string use `function_name('arg')` or `function_name("arg")`.

So in your code change:

```
<button type="button" onclick="paz(<?php echo json_encode(chkdelt); ?>);">Click</button>
```

to

```
<button type="button" onclick="paz('<?php echo json_encode(chkdelt); ?>');">Click</button>
```

Also I'll suggest you to use `<input type="button" />` Instead of `<button>` & I think if `chkdelt` is variable name in php you'll need to use `$` sign before it and use `json_encode($chkdelt)`.

Hope it'll help you.. Cheers :)!

Comment: No change..When I click that delete button...value is not passed to javascript. If value was being passed, alert would have shown the values, @Vedant Terkar

Comment: @TheJoker Can you post the actual `html` output after processing `php`? In your browser open that `php` page and then use `view source` to get actual `html`. Or Simply try alerting `a` in your `function paz(a)` what is the output of `a`?

Comment: <button type="button"  onclick="pazz('" chkdelt"');">Delete users</button> @ Vedant Terkar

Comment: <input type="checkbox" id="chkdelt[1]" name="chkdelt[]" value="1">

Comment: are you using `json_encode(chkdelt);` or `json_encode($chkdelt)`? What is `chkdelt`? a variable in `php` right?

Comment: chkdel is the checkbox containing array. it has php values. @Vedant Terkar